# I want to make a conditional property bind for 2 inputs

Tags: input, angular6, property-binding

I have a list of animals for different types like cats and dogs. 
when I choose an animal in the list, for edition, I need to assinged the value to the child component. The Child Component have two inputs in the edit.ts: @input cat:animal,  @input dog:animal; 
I just want to pass a data for one of those property bind.

I tried a two conditional selectors :

```
<app-component *ngIf="conditionTypeDog" [Dog]="animalchoose">
</app-component>
<app-component *ngIf="conditionTypeCat" [cat]="animalchoose">
</app-component>
```

in the component we have:

```
@input dog: Dog; 
@input cat: Cat;
```

let's admitting that Dog and Cat classes are inherited from animal:

```
Dog extends Animal; 
Cat extends Animal; 

Animal {
 propertygeneric1:number;
 propertygeneric2: String;
}

cat extends animal { 
property1: boolean
property2: String;
} 

Dog extends animal { 
propertyDog1:number; 
propertyDog2:String; 
}
```

I want a solution like this:

```
<app-component *ngIf="conditionEdit" [Dog|Cat] = "animalchoose"> 
</app-component>
```

So I want that animal chosen to be conditionally assigned  to one of the types, there are a way to make the animal chosen to be assigned the Dog, or  for the cat?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no such thing as conditionally choosing which property to bind in angular. However you can accomplish same behavior in different ways. One I can think of is to use `@Input` setters using `instance of` operator to determine the type of input and assign it to relevant property of class.

```js
  private dog: Dog;
  private cat: Cat;

  @Input() set animal(val: Animal) {
    if (!val) {
      this.cat = null;
      this.dog = null;
    }
    if (val instanceof Dog) {
      this.cat = null;
      this.dog = val;
    }
    if (val instanceof Cat) {
      this.dog = null;
      this.cat = val;
    }
  }
```

here is a simple demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jerc5p

Comment: Oh thanks , but if I use this solutions I missed the especific atribuited of the inherited Class.  Like, if dog has the property barking, it won't be present in the animal;

Comment: what do you mean? nothing gets lost in this way.

Comment: Yes the property barking is not in the animal class , so if I passed an object Dog to the child , they will lost the property barking, or not? 
I Have this concern because I'm from traditional java, I dont know about typescript one.

Comment: it will not get lost. just try and see on the demo above, you can edit it.  forget java this is typescript man ;)

Comment: Thanks again I'll try lately in my note because I'm travel and i didn't bring my note, so i will try on my smart/Android.